# Problems with MinimalBy, MaximalBy, SortBy

Tags: filtering, sorting

```
n = 1;

MinimalBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
MaximalBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
SortBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
```

They give:

> {{1, -1}}
>
> {{0, 0}}
>
> {{1, -1}, {0, 0}}

But

```
n = 1.;

MinimalBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
MaximalBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
SortBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
```

work fine:

> {{0, 0}}
>
> {{1, -1}}
>
> {{0, 0}, {1, -1}}

Version : 10.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: In the documentation, look up the first example under "possible issues" on the `Sort` page

Answer (score 3):

All these functions use `Sort` to perform their calculations. `Sort` doesn't work with irrational numbers such as $\sqrt 2$ which you get after taking `EuclideanDistance[{1, 1}, {0, 0}]`. Simple example like `Sort[{2, Sqrt[2]}]` also gives you the wrong answer

> {2, Sqrt[2]}

The irrational number needs to be changed to a real number by adding the floating point `Sort[{2, Sqrt[2.0]}]`. Then, as you mentioned, the result is correct

> {1.41421, 2}

As nicely added by Szabolcz, you can also use `TakeLargestBy` where the numerical evaluation `N` can be applied for sorting (NOTE: `TakeLargestBy` gives larger values first)

```
TakeLargestBy[{Sqrt[2], 2}, N, 2]
```

> {2, Sqrt[2]}

Comment: In recent versions one can also use `TakeLargestBy` instead of `MaximalBy`.  `TakeLargestBy` sorts by numerical magnitude.

Comment: Thank you @Pavlo and @Szabolcs. I understand the behaviour of `Sort` and try with TakeLargestBy.

Answer (score 1):

```
EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] & /@ {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {0., 0.}, {1., -1.}}
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[2], 2, 1.41421, 2.}
> ```

```
Sort[%]
```

> ```
> {1.41421, 2, 2., Sqrt[2]}
> ```

```
FullForm[%]
```

> ```
>  List[1.4142135623730951`,2,2.`,Power[2,Rational[1,2]]]
> ```

Try

```
MinimalBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, N@EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
MaximalBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, N@EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
SortBy[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}}, N@EuclideanDistance[{1, n}, #] &]
```